# Filter parameter from DT doesn't work with all the columns

Tags: r, filter, datatable, dt

I am using DT package and `filter='top'` and I realised that some columns can give you the chance to click the different options of the column, but some columns don't give you that.

Here for example, you can click the options in the "am" column. However, if you try to do the same with the column named "model", you cannot.

[image]
[image: image3]
[image: image2]

Does anyone know if there is way to have the same filter in the first column (model)?

The code:

```
library(DT)

mtcars2 = mtcars[c(1:3,9)]
mtcars2$am = factor(mtcars$am, c(0, 1), c('automatic', 'manual'))

datatable(
  mtcars2, colnames = c('model' = 1),
  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
  options = list(
    pageLength = 10
  )
)
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: You can type characters in the `Model` filter : try for example `M`, it works. The difference with `am` is that it's not a factor with levels proposed as multiple choice

Comment: @Waldi Oh god, I didn't think about the differences. So if I want to have the multiple choice, I have to transform the column into a factor.

Thanks!!